# Build failure and mojo exception while running mvn clean install in visual studio code

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, build

I am executing mvn clean install in a terminal in visual studio code.
I have written all the java jdbc code for connecting database to my java application.
When I run the mvn clean install ,it is showing me build failure and mojo exception.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question lacks details. Please provide your code and the exception with its stack trace. Also, take a look at minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

set JAVA_HOME to jdk not to JDK_DIR/jre